# Django: Duplicate action when I press Follow or Unfollow button

Tags: python, django

I am doing CS50w project4 problem, so I have to build a Social Media app. This problem has a part where in the profile of the user a follow and unfollow button has to be available. My problem is when I press the follow or unfollow button, this increase or decrease the followers and the people that the user follow.

views.py

```
def seguir(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        accion = request.POST.get('accion')
        usuario_accion = request.POST.get('usuario')
        usuario = request.user.username

        # Comprobación de si ya lo esta siguiendo y recuperación de información de usuarios
        perfil_usuario = User.objects.get(username=usuario)
        perfil_usuario_accion = User.objects.get(username=usuario_accion)
        esta_siguiendo = perfil_usuario.seguidos.filter(username=usuario_accion).exists()

        if accion == 'follow':

            # Si no lo esta siguiendo se añade a la lista de seguidos de uno y de seguidores del otro
            if esta_siguiendo == False:
                perfil_usuario_accion.seguidores.add(perfil_usuario)
                perfil_usuario.seguidos.add(perfil_usuario_accion)

            # Redirección a la página del usuario seguido
            return render(request, "network/profile.html", {
                "profile_user": perfil_usuario_accion,
                "logged_user": 0
            })
        
        else:

            # Comprobación de que lo siga
            if esta_siguiendo:
                perfil_usuario.seguidos.remove(perfil_usuario_accion)
                perfil_usuario_accion.seguidores.remove(perfil_usuario)
            
            return render(request, "network/profile.html", {
                "profile_user": perfil_usuario_accion,
                "logged_user": 0
            })
```

profile.html

```
{% extends "network/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
    <h1 id="titulo-perfil">{{ profile_user.username }} profile page</h1>
    <div id="contenedor-seguir">
        <div id="seguidores">Followers: {{ profile_user.seguidores.count }}</div>
        <div id="seguidos">Following: {{ profile_user.seguidos.count }}</div>
    </div>
    {% if logged_user == 0 %}
        <form id="contenedor-botones" action="{% url 'follow' %}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="hidden" name="usuario" value="{{ profile_user.username }}">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="accion" value="follow">Follow</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary", name="accion" value="unfollow">Unfollow</button>
        </form>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    seguidores = models.ManyToManyField('self', symmetrical='false', related_name='tesiguen', blank=True)
    seguidos = models.ManyToManyField('self', symmetrical='false', related_name='siguiendo', blank=True)
```

I want that when the user press the follow button, the follower of the people he are following increase and the followers counter of the other one increase in one too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that you wrote **`symmetrical='false'`** as a *string literal*, and the truthiness of that string is, well, `True`. You should use the `False` constant, so `symmetrical=False`.

But you are overcomplicating things. Django is perfectly capable to handle a [**`ManyToManyField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField) in the two directions.

Indeed, we can define this as:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    seguidores = models.ManyToManyField(
        'self', symmetrical=False, related_name='seguidos', blank=True
    )
```

So here if *A* adds *B* to the `seguidores`, then *A* will appear in the `seguidos` of *B*, so it is automatically reflecting that.

So the view then is simplified to:

```
def seguir(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        accion = request.POST.get('accion')
        usuario_accion = request.POST.get('usuario')
        usuario = request.user.username

        # Comprobación de si ya lo esta siguiendo y recuperación de información de usuarios
        perfil_usuario = User.objects.get(username=usuario)
        perfil_usuario_accion = User.objects.get(username=usuario_accion)
        esta_siguiendo = perfil_usuario.seguidos.filter(
            username=usuario_accion
        ).exists()

        if accion == 'follow':

            # Si no lo esta siguiendo se añade a la lista de seguidos de uno y de seguidores del otro
            if not esta_siguiendo:
                perfil_usuario_accion.seguidores.add(perfil_usuario)

            # Redirección a la página del usuario seguido
            return render(
                request,
                "network/profile.html",
                {"profile_user": perfil_usuario_accion, "logged_user": 0},
            )

        else:

            # Comprobación de que lo siga
            if esta_siguiendo:
                perfil_usuario.seguidos.remove(perfil_usuario_accion)
                perfil_usuario_accion.seguidores.remove(perfil_usuario)

            return render(
                request,
                "network/profile.html",
                {"profile_user": perfil_usuario_accion, "logged_user": 0},
            )
```

and the template remains the same.

Comment: This solve the problem! Thanks for the response and for the explanation of how the related_name property works. I am going to use it in the way you explain and study well the ManytoManyField.